# returning mySQL errors from php - nothing being returned on error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file which performs a series of insert queries. If any of the queries generates an error, I would like to return the error message and query string and roll back all the queries

So far I have this:

```
mysql_query("SET autocommit=0;");
mysql_query("BEGIN;");
$sql ="SOME MALFORMED QUERY";

mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_error()){
    mysql_query("rollback;");
    $arr = array("returnCode" => 0, "returnMessage" => "Query failed: " .$sql. mysql_error());
    echo json_encode($arr);
    die();
}
```

However, In javascript all I'm seeing returned in the return message JSON field is 'Query failed: '. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `ROLLBACK` query: as explained in the manual, [mysql_error](http://fr.php.net/mysql_error) returns the error text from the **last** MySQL function. Since you used mysql_query again, the previous error is lost.

I suggest this code:

```
mysql_query("SET autocommit=0;");
mysql_query("BEGIN;");
$sql ="SOME MALFORMED QUERY";

mysql_query($sql);
$error = mysql_error();
if($error){
    mysql_query("rollback;");
    $arr = array("returnCode" => 0, "returnMessage" => "Query failed: $sql, Error: $error");
    echo json_encode($arr);
    die();
}
```

Executing `ROLLBACK` in case an error occurs seems useless. The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html) explains:
Rolling back can be a slow operation that may occur implicitly **without the user having explicitly asked for it (for example, when an error occurs)**

The following code should then be enough:

```
mysql_query("SET autocommit=0;");
mysql_query("BEGIN;");
$sql ="SOME MALFORMED QUERY";

mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_error()){
    $arr = array("returnCode" => 0, "returnMessage" => "Query failed: $sql, Error: ".mysql_error());
    echo json_encode($arr);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Although, I wonder why the $sql variable is blank as well?

Comment: Maybe this wasn't entirely clear: I had posted only the modified part of your code. I just updated my answer by including the full modified version.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

`$arr = array("returnCode" => 0, "returnMessage" => "Query failed: " .$sql. sql_error());`

be

`$arr = array("returnCode" => 0, "returnMessage" => "Query failed: " .$sql. **mysql_error()**);`

Comment: sorry! it should be that, but I made an error when copying the code over. I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Probably the expression `"Query failed: " .$sql. sql_error()` is not well formed.
The correct form is:

```
"Query failed: " . $sql . mysql_error()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PDO and its built-in transactions support.

```
<?php

// create PDO instance as $db here
// don't forget to set error mode to 'exception'

try {
    $db->beginTransaction();
    // do your queries here, i.e. $db->exec('BOGUS');
    $db->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

It will give you any error encountered as the exception message when it throws one.